# Does the maximum voltage on a multimeter refer to the maximum difference between the two points or the difference between the points and ground?

Tags: current-measurement, high-voltage, multimeter

I am trying to measure the current in a high voltage DC circuit (over 10 kV) and have an idea I think will work, but I want to make sure before I break equipment or create a dangerous situation due to a misunderstanding.

My plan is to use a multimeter to measure the current (in milli-amps) over a 10 ohm resistor placed in series with the load (the resistance of the load is not known) and between the load and ground. As I am using a normal multimeter with a maximum voltage rating of 600 VDC, I want to make sure that this maximum voltage refers to the potential difference between the two points that I'm measuring and not to the actual voltages involved and that I can accurately measure the current. Additionally, I want to make sure that (even if that is true and the multimeter can measure the current in this way) this method will not make the multimeter charged and dangerous to touch.

If what I'm suggesting will not work, is there a different way to measure current that I am not considering?

Comment: Think about this: if the multimeter does not have **ANY** connection to earth/ground, how can is "see" that voltage? Also: it worries me in ways that you cannot imagine that you're working on something with 10 kV DC yet you have to ask this question. Perhaps you should educate yourself more before working with high voltages?

Comment: The ratings on the multimeter are for **voltages between its connections**, that doesn't mean you can safely measure **any** voltage, do you think it would be safe to use it to measure 10 V (much less than what the meter can handle) at a device that is at 1 MV (Mega Volt) above earth/ground  **while you're standing on earth, holding that multimeter**? Across what will that 1 MV be? Hint: you will not survive this.

Comment: Thank you for your quick replies! Your response matches my understanding of what would happen (including the danger of the multimeter itself becoming dangerously charged). Is there a different technique for current measurement that would not entail such risk, besides having the measurement device placed far away from the display (as I plan to do anyway)?

Comment: What you are trying to do is outside the scope of the meter's intended use. Can you measure the current on the **ground side**? This is much safer. If you use the meter to measure current on the high side, you need to isolate the meter sufficiently so you don't get an arc from inside the meter to surrounding objects, including you (i.e., don't touch the meter).

Comment: Find or hire someone who is qualified and competent to work with high voltages.  It's not worth risking your life if you don't know exactly how to do it.

Comment: @Alix I'd recommend using an opto-isolator and a relaxation oscillator to measure the voltage across the current-measuring resistor and turn it into pulses of light that you can safely handle over a fiber link to where ever you and the pulse rate measuring device will be located. What dynamic range and precision do you require?

Comment: Also consider using a **wireless solution** where the **measurement** part of the meter is separated from its **display**, for example: https://www.fluke.com/en/product/electrical-testing/digital-multimeters/fluke-233  as long as you connect the meter with the high voltage **off**, this should be safe enough. Similar solutions exist using Bluetooth or Wifi.

Comment: @qrk, I've looked over my project and am going to try to switch things around to measure on the ground side as you suggest (it's more practical physically too, so that's convenient). 

Bimpelrkkie, thank you for your concern, though I should clarify that I am entirely aware that I'm in over my head and that I'm undertaking this project with oversight from people who know far more than I do. Eventually, my plan is to have an entirely separate display system managed with a raspberry pi so that there is absolutely no risk where measurement is concerned.

Comment: At >10kV wrt earth the multimeter will not only be dangerous to touch but dangerous to get **anywhere close to**.  The meter would also have to be insulated from ground because the case will not necessarily be designed for that level of insulation, and an arc to ground would destroy the meter most likely (or could kill some person that happens to form part of the current path).

Answer (score 1):

For battery powered and handheld multimeters, the voltage to ground doesn't matter because they are floating devices.

I have seen such multimeters used in exactly the scenario you mention: to measure small currents in a HV rack with the instrumentation sitting at 10 kV.

The main difficulties are: a) how to power the instruments and b) how to operate them.

If you use local battery power and only interact by watching the multimeter, there is no problem.

However, do note, that whenever there is a short circuit in your HV load (which can very easily happen due to arcs) the full HV can drop momentarily across your series resistor and thus across your multimeter.